# For a new account with an existing login, cookie requirement lacking action method

Tags: bug, login, cookies

I had an account on a Stack Exchange site, not Law or Meta. I wanted to post on Law, so I had to confirm and create a new account with the existing login.

Clarification: My browser was and is set to accept cookies on a session basis, not persistently, but I don't want persistent cookies. Evidently, the website didn't notice.

Law said, "Law Stack Exchange requires cookies for authentication -- are your browser cookies enabled for this domain?" Fine, but there's no way to respond, except by refreshing the page, which can be risky, and that got me a 404 error and I had to log in again.

So I emailed Stack Exchange, was told to go to Meta, and essentially the process repeated in the last hour or so, with "Meta Stack Exchange requires cookies for authentication -- are your browser cookies enabled for this domain?" and a 404 error. This behavior makes the site look broken and probably should be repaired.

Additional info: I read the other thread newly linked to in this one, near the top. If users should know that procedure, please state it in the message, although I think fixing it altogether would give users a better experience.

Comment: Do you not understand how to enable cookies in your browser? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Cookies are and were enabled (I edited the opening post to add that). The issue is not that.